# Cause of upper-back pain?

Tags: weightlifting, injury, back-pain

Two weeks ago I was using [this machine](https://atlantisstrength.com/app/uploads/2022/01/e352_4.png) for lateral raises as part of my push-day weightlifting routine. On my third or fourth set I suddenly felt pain in my upper back, between the shoulder blades. I eased off a bit but did finish my workout.

The pain went away quickly but could be caused to come back by looking down at my toes. That improved over the next few days until it was down to maybe 10% of the initial pain level.

Eight days after that first workout I used [this pull-over machine](https://gym80.de/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/gym80_3012_ueberzugmaschine_overview-scaled.jpg) and that immediately caused the same pain in the same area during the first set. Once again, I eased off but finished the workout, but now the pain is worse and has not improved notably in a week.

The pain is sharp. When I look straight down, I feel it in the horizontal center of my upper back; when I look down and left, the pain moves slightly toward the right of the spine, when I look down and right, the pain moves slightly toward the left. When I don't look down, I don't feel pain. My chin has to be fairly close to my chest to reproduce the pain.

What might have happened here and how can I fix it?